# What does this circuit on my battery do?

Tags: batteries, pins

I have a Parrot Mambo which has a very low flight time, so I would like to tether it up with some power supply. However, the battery uses 3 instead of 2 pins and i'm not sure what each of them to. I have pried open of one of the batteries, and found a circuit inside.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What does this circuit do? Is there any documentation of this circuit somewhere? I would really like to know what each of the 3 pins does, and how I can emulate them using some external power supply.

Comment: The protection circuit is for the battery, not the drone.  You are probably not going to be able to fly this with a tether, for that to work you would need a system with higher voltage lower current motors.  On the bench you could use a 4 volt supply but the short flight time likely indicates draw in the range of several amps so you will see severe voltage drop with a tether of reasonable weight and will trip/confuse the battery low voltage detection.  Damage isn't entirely impossible from extreme power oscillation.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks, I'm probably only going to use a wire of 1 to 2 meters long so the voltage fluctuations should be good

Comment: I expect you'll find that either it doesn't work very well, or your drone doesn't fly very well with a heavy wire hanging from it

Comment: @ChrisStratton but a decent power supply should be able to regulate the voltage right?

Comment: In theory... in practice, you'd need an additional pair of wires to measure the voltage at the drone end of the cable after the drops there, and likely your power supply wouldn't have the bandwidth to match the load variation; rather than compensating the losses, mis-timed effort would kill the drone.  Conceptually if you wanted to do this, you'd find systems suited to 12v or more operation to reduce the current and thus the losses compared to a system designed to run around 4 volts and thus draw three times as much current.

Comment: In theory you could perhaps use a high voltage tether and find a buck regulator light enough to fly, but the engineering will be challenging.  What it really comes down to is that you need to buy a replacement for a tired battery, or switch to an aircraft engineered for greater flight time.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the battery protection circuit of the Li-Po battery. It prevents over-current over-voltage and under-voltage as a minimum in most Li-Po battery systems. This circuit and its parameters are set by the manufacturer, for the particular Li-Po it is meant to protect. Generally it is not a good idea to tinker around with this as it could render the battery potentially insecure and dangerous. You would need to contact the manufacturer to obtain the details of this circuit you request as they are generally not made public for a good reason. However the silicon device with the marking VC55 should be easy enough to find I guess if you look hard enough for it. Then you may better understand how the circuit works. Having said that, the 3 pin on such a system may be allocated to a thermistance output for measuring the battery temperature directly. Those that only provide two pins don't have the thermistor installed or available.
Hope this makes sense.
Regards,
citizen